# A different approach to using a SQL cursors in SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I am writing a stored procedure in SQL and I am currently in the position of having 3 nested cursors (which isn;t running quite how I would like). I'd appreciate any suggestions on how I can break out of the cursor is the solution trap

I basically have 2 tables (both temporary during the SP populated by SELECT statements from the application)

1 - A list of tables, columns and datatypes

```
Table1 | SURNAME  | VARCHAR
       | SEX      | VARCHAR
       | DOB      | DATETIME
------------------------------
Table2 | ADDRESS  | VARCHAR
------------------------------
Table3 | SALARY   | INT
------------------------------
Table4 | USERNAME | VARCHAR
       | PASSWORD | VARCHAR
```

2 - A one column list of user numbers

My application has to loop through each user number, then for each user I have to loop through the distinct tables (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4) and see if there is any data in that tabel for that user (using dyanmic SQL so I can pass the table name as a parameter). If there is, I then have to then loop through each column that relates to that table and build a dynamic SQL INSERT statement

So for user number 2...
any data in Table1? No - skip
any data in Table2? Yes - copy rows into temp table then build dynamic SQL for ADDRESS value
any data in Table3? No - skip
any data in Table4? Yes - copy rows into temp table then build dynamic SQL for USERNAME and PASSWORD columns

The cursor approach works fine from a functionality point of view but performance is a little slow. I've made sure the 2 source tables are as tight as possible, when creating my dynamic SQL I copy the relevant rows only into a temp table to process, I've made my cursors FAST_FORWARD and READ_ONLY

Is there any approach I can take instead?

ORIGINAL CODE POSTED AS REQUESTED:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MembersToDelete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##MembersToDelete
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempDataTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempDataTable
DELETE FROM @CompSetTable
DELETE FROM DataRefreshDeletes
DELETE FROM DataRefreshInserts


--BUILD THE INDIVIDUAL SELECT STATEMENTS INTO A TEMP TABLE
SET @RowPosition = 1;
SET @inSelectFilter = @inSelectFilter + ';';
SET @inSelectFilter = REPLACE(@inSelectFilter,'/','''');
WHILE LEN(@inSelectFilter) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%;%',@inSelectFilter) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectParameter = SUBSTRING(@inSelectFilter, 0, PATINDEX('%;%',@inSelectFilter))
        SET @inSelectFilter = SUBSTRING(@inSelectFilter, LEN(@SelectParameter + ';') + 1,LEN(@inSelectFilter))
        IF @RowPosition = 1
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @SelectParameterTable VALUES ('WHERE ' + @SelectParameter)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @SelectParameterTable VALUES (' AND ' + @SelectParameter)
            END
        SET @RowPosition = @RowPosition + 1        
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SelectParameter = @inSelectFilter
        SET @inSelectFilter = NULL
    END
END

--BUILD THE COMPLETE DELETE STATEMENT
SET @SelectParameter = NULL;
SELECT @SelectParameter = COALESCE(@SelectParameter, '') + statementString FROM @SelectParameterTable 

--INSERT THE MEMBER NUMBERS INTO THE TEMP TABLE
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##MembersToDelete') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##MembersToDelete
SET @SelectParameter = 'SELECT MEMBNO INTO ##MembersToDelete FROM BASIC ' + @SelectParameter
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SelectParameter
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Print 'The following statement could not be run - please check the syntax...'
    Print @SelectParameter
    GOTO cleanUpAndFinish
END CATCH
SELECT @MembersToDeleteCount = COUNT(*) FROM ##MembersToDelete

Print '##MembersToDelete TABLE BUILT - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109)

--BUILD LIST OF COMPENDIA TABLES (ORDERED BY DSET)
DELETE FROM @CompSetTable
INSERT INTO @CompSetTable SELECT d.DSNAME, c.column_name, d.DSET, c.data_type FROM DICTIONARY d, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE DNUM = -1 AND DSET < 250 AND c.table_name = d.DSNAME ORDER BY d.DSET

Print '@CompSetTable TABLE BUILT - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109)
DECLARE setInsertCursor CURSOR GLOBAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR SELECT DISTINCT setName, setNumber FROM @CompSetTable ORDER BY setNumber

--WE NOW HAVE THE LIST OF MEMBER NUMBERS AND THE LIST OF TABLES TO BUILD THE DELETE STATEMENT
SELECT @MemberNumberString = COALESCE(@MemberNumberString + ', ', '') + LTRIM(STR(MEMBNO)) FROM ##MembersToDelete 

DECLARE setDeleteCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY SCROLL FOR SELECT DISTINCT setName, setNumber FROM @CompSetTable ORDER BY setNumber
OPEN setDeleteCursor
FETCH LAST FROM setDeleteCursor INTO @SetName, @SetNumber
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @DeleteStatementTable VALUES ('DELETE FROM ' + UPPER(@SetName) + ' WHERE MEMBNO IN (' + @MemberNumberString + ')')
        FETCH PRIOR FROM setDeleteCursor INTO @SetName, @SetNumber
        END
CLOSE setDeleteCursor
DEALLOCATE setDeleteCursor

Print '@DeleteStatementTable TABLE BUILT - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109)

DECLARE memberInsertCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT MEMBNO FROM ##MembersToDelete
OPEN memberInsertCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM memberInsertCursor INTO @MemberNumber
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --NOW BUILD THE INSERT STATEMENTS
    OPEN setInsertCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM setInsertCursor INTO @SetName, @SetNumber
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            --CHECK IF MEMBER HAS ANY ROWS IN THIS SET - IF NOT, SKIP
            SET @ROWCOUNT = 0
            SELECT @COUNTSQL = N'SELECT @countOUT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @SetName + ' WHERE MEMBNO = ' + LTRIM(STR(@MemberNumber))  
            EXEC sp_executesql @COUNTSQL, N'@countOUT INT OUTPUT', @countOUT=@ROWCOUNT OUTPUT;
            IF @ROWCOUNT = 0
                BEGIN
                                GOTO nextSet
                END

                                SET @VALUES = NULL;     

            --DROP TEMPORARY TABLE
            IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempDataTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TempDataTable

            --POPULATE TEMPORARY TABLE
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ##TempDataTable FROM ' + @SetName + ' WHERE MEMBNO = ' + LTRIM(STR(@MemberNumber))
            EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

            --BUILD SELECT STATEMENT
            SET @INSERTSTRING = NULL
            SET @INSERTSTRING = CAST('' as nVarChar(MAX)) + 'SELECT ''INSERT INTO ' + @SetName + ' VALUES ('''

            DECLARE setColumnCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR SELECT columnName, dataType FROM @CompSetTable WHERE setName = @SetName
            OPEN setColumnCursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM setColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName, @DataType
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN       

                IF @DataType IN ('text','varchar','nvarchar','ntext','char')
                BEGIN
                    SET @INSERTSTRING = CAST('' as nVarChar(MAX)) + @INSERTSTRING + ''''' + ISNULL(' + @ColumnName + ',''NULL'') + '''''','''
                END
                ELSE IF @DataType IN ('int','decimal','smallint','numeric','tinyint','bigint','float')
                BEGIN
                    --SET @INSERTSTRING = @INSERTSTRING + ' + ' + @COLUMNNAMENULL + ' + '','''
                    SET @INSERTSTRING = CAST('' as nVarChar(MAX)) + @INSERTSTRING + ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),' + @ColumnName + '),''NULL'')' + ' + '','''
                END
                ELSE IF @DataType IN ('datetime')
                BEGIN
                    --SET @INSERTSTRING = @INSERTSTRING + ' + ' + @COLUMNNAMENULL + ' + '','''
                    SET @INSERTSTRING = CAST('' as nVarChar(MAX)) + @INSERTSTRING + ''''' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),' + @ColumnName + '),''NULL'')' + ' + '''''','''
                END

                FETCH NEXT FROM setColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName, @DataType
            END
            CLOSE setColumnCursor
            DEALLOCATE setColumnCursor      

            SET @INSERTSTRING = @INSERTSTRING + '+'')'''
            SET @INSERTSTRING = @INSERTSTRING + ' FROM ##TempDataTable'

            INSERT INTO @InsertStatementTable EXECUTE sp_executesql @INSERTSTRING

        nextSet:
            FETCH NEXT FROM setInsertCursor INTO @SetName, @SetNumber
            END

FETCH NEXT FROM memberInsertCursor INTO @MemberNumber
END
CLOSE memberInsertCursor
DEALLOCATE memberInsertCursor

CLOSE setInsertCursor
DEALLOCATE setInsertCursor
```

Comment: Might be easier to understand what you are doing if you post your existing code - i.e. the existing stored proc

Comment: Each of your tables is missing a user number column, I think.  Otherwise, how do you correlate between your tables?

Comment: @TimCoker - there is no correlation - it is "For each row in user table perform an action using each row in the Table table". So if I have 20 rows in the user table and 10 rows in the Table table, I will loop 20 times and for each loop, loop 10 times.

Comment: @FergusBown - original post edited to include code

Comment: Are you familiar with cross joins?  Sounds like what this is.  You can cross join all your tables to get one large result (every permutation) and then operate on that result.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't follow your question correctly but what's wrong with using 'insert...select' where the select joins all these tables?

Comment: Thanks @Leo - I'm building dynamic SQL to insert into a table (I'm inserting the actual dynamic SQL string rather than the result)

Comment: what's the difference? It's the same approach, same principles

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to implement precedence.  I question whether you actually need the original table.  If not, just use `not exists`

```
insert into . . .
    select . . . 
    from Table1;

insert into . . .
    select . . .
    from Table2
    where not exists (select 1
                      from Table1
                      where Table1.userid = Table2.userid and
                            Table1.colname = Table2.colname
                     );

insert into . . .
    select . . .
    from Table3
    where not exists (select 1
                      from Table1
                      where Table1.userid = Table3.userid and
                            Table1.colname = Table3.colname
                     ) and
          not exists  (select 1
                      from Table2
                      where Table2.userid = Table3.userid and
                            Table2.colname = Table3.colname
                     );
```

If you are actually conditionally choosing the columns from each table, then you might have to construct the above as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you add ID columns in each table and index it you can make selection a lot faster. Give unique index for ID column and that's it. You can improve the speed of entire action a lot.